# How to solve $2x-\cos x=0$ using Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to solve the equation

$$2x-\cos x=0$$

using Lipschitz.

I know that $\cos x$ is Lipschitz-Cont. since

$$|\cos x-\cos y|\leq |-\sin z||x-y| \leq |x-y|$$

So i know that $cos x$ is $1$-Lipschitz. But how to continue i solving the equation? I thing this has something to do with the Banach fix point theorem. Any suggestions?

Comment: $x\mapsto \frac12 \cos x$ is $1/2$-Lipschitz ($\therefore$ a contraction map). What does BFT tell you?

Comment: It tells me "$x^*$ can be found as follows: start with an arbitrary element $x_0$ and define a sequence $(x_n)$ by with $x_n \rightarrow x^*$". Can I take for example $x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{x_n}{n}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(x)=\frac{\cos x}{2}$ is not just Lipschitz, but a contraction, meaning $f$ has a unique fixed point.

Comment: OK, so I can apply the banach fix point theorem? I know that $x=\frac{\cos x}{2}$ but what gives me this now?

Comment: if $f(x)=\frac{\cos x}{2}$ and we know that $f$ is a contraction, what do you know about the number of solutions to $f(x)=x$?

Comment: Also you can use the intermediate value theorem to quickly note that the solution lies between $0$ and $\pi/4$

Comment: Sorry, but how can I find the fixed point?